# ISNULL Syntax Challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to figure out the syntax issue here.

This works, but returns nulls;

```
SELECT jo.Job_Operation, jo.Job, jo.Work_Center, jo.Operation_Service, jo.Est_Total_Hrs,
    (SELECT SUM(jot.Act_Run_Hrs)
    FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation_Time jot
    WHERE jot.Job_Operation = jo.Job_Operation) AS Cost
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation jo
WHERE jo.Job = 'A5076027'
```

So I'm trying to use ISNULL here but I get an error:

```
SELECT jo.Job_Operation, jo.Job, jo.Work_Center, jo.Operation_Service, jo.Est_Total_Hrs,
    (ISNULL(SELECT SUM(jot.Act_Run_Hrs)
    FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation_Time jot
    WHERE jot.Job_Operation = jo.Job_Operation,0)) AS Cost
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation jo
WHERE jo.Job = 'A5076027'
```

The error is:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do joins in subquery selects if you can avoid it.  In your case, convert your query to use a regular join, then use `ISNULL` on that instead.

Comment: You've got the second parameter of `ISNULL` nested one level too deeply inside the parentheses; @Adam Silenko's answer should work

Comment: The use of a correlated subquery here is fine (although some would use `apply` instead).

Comment: if you use subquery as parameter, you must put it in brackets

Comment: Anytime you get errors in queries like this, look closely at your open & close parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT jo.Job_Operation, jo.Job, jo.Work_Center, jo.Operation_Service, jo.Est_Total_Hrs,
    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(jot.Act_Run_Hrs)
    FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation_Time jot
    WHERE jot.Job_Operation = jo.Job_Operation),0) AS Cost
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation jo
WHERE jo.Job = 'A5076027'
```

Comment: Sum never returns null, it just returns 0 I thought

Comment: sum returns null if there is no `not null` value, because all aggregate functions ignore null, also [sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187810%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), subquery also can return null ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a correlated subquery here. This seems to me like a standard left join is all that is required.

```
SELECT jo.Job_Operation
    , jo.Job
    , jo.Work_Center
    , jo.Operation_Service
    , jo.Est_Total_Hrs
    , SUM(isnull(jot.Act_Run_Hrs, 0)) AS Cost
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation jo
left join PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation_Time jot ON jot.Job_Operation = jo.Job_Operation
WHERE jo.Job = 'A5076027'
GROUP BY
    jo.Job_Operation
    , jo.Job
    , jo.Work_Center
    , jo.Operation_Service
    , jo.Est_Total_Hrs
```

Comment: Thanks @AdamSilenko. :)

Comment: I don't think sum ever returns null

Comment: @BrianWhite that is correct but it won't affect anything here. Many people prefer to see it "just in case". :)

Comment: Ah, it doesn't return null when there are no values, but it will if there are no rows.  Got it

Answer (score 2):

This is far more legible in my opinion

```
SELECT
   jo.Job_Operation, jo.Job, jo.Work_Center, jo.Operation_Service, jo.Est_Total_Hrs
   ,ISNULL(jot.[SumAct_Run_Hrs],0) AS Cost
FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation jo
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Job_Operation,SUM(Act_Run_Hrs) [SumAct_Run_Hrs]
    FROM PRODUCTION.dbo.Job_Operation_Time
    GROUP BY Job_Operation
) jot ON jot.Job_Operation = jo.Job_Operation
WHERE jo.Job = 'A5076027'
```